# How can I run multiple parallel projects with ReadyAPI? (Command line way)

Tags: api, rest, ready-api, test-runner

I have two ReadyAPI projects that I want to run in parallel (via command line) but I do not know if I'm giving the exact instructions to the testRunner.

I have a testRunner that I run from the cmd with these lines:

```
call testrunner "X:Path\project1.xml"
call testrunner "X:Path\project2.xml"
```

However, It's only running the first project and no signal from the second one.

Any thoughts? If there is an easier way than the command line I would appreciate listening to it.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

for running parallel tests from multiple ReadyAPI projects you should take a look at TestEngine.

Its a standalone runner of tests, and has the added benefit of things list job prioritization, queueing of tests and more.

https://support.smartbear.com/testengine/docs/about.html